# mysql update an column from another table

Tags: mysql

```
Table1:
id  name  value
===================
1   Jane   28
2   Joe    35

Table2:
id  name  value  integer
=========================
1   Jane    28      379
2   Joe     30      325
2   Joe     32      380
1   Jane    28      385
```

Table1 contains information about user: ID, Name and Value.
Table2 contains information about changes: ID, Name, Value and Integer.
Integer is a value thats always increase and changes about twice a day.

I want to transfer the value from table1 for a specific ID and that value to table2 and put that value at the last line.

In this example I want 
ID: 2 
Value: 35 
in Table1 to relace

ID: 2
Value: 32 
in Table2. And I need to use the Integer in some way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `interger` the column which tells the latest in the `table2` then you can use the `update join` as

```
update table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
join ( 
  select max(`integer`) as `integer`,id 
  from table2 
  group by id
)x 
on x.id = t2.id and x.`integer` = t2.`integer` 
set t1.value = t2.value 
where t1.id = 2 ;
```

Comment: Great response. Worked perfectly. 
I can honestly say I'm not that great with mysql commands :)

Is there any easy way to make it work the other way around?
As update Table1's Value: 35 with Table2's Value 32 on ID:2

Comment: Well join update is much better than selecting and then looping through. And if your joining keys are indexed then it can handle millions of data in a matter of time.